# XAudio2Create failed after the update 2021/4/20

Tags: c++, xaudio2

Windows10 version 20H2.

I followed every step-Getting started with XAudio2-How to: Initialize XAudio2.

The link is here.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/xaudio2/getting-started

The code worked before the update.
But now when I try to do something like this:

```
pXAudio2->CreateSourceVoice( &pSourceVoice, (WAVEFORMATEX*)&wfx )
```

It is said the value of pSourceVoice is nullptr.

I'm sure I have done all these code down here.

```
Microsoft::WRL::ComPtr<IXAudio2> XAudio2;
HRESULT hr;
if ( FAILED(hr = XAudio2Create( &XAudio2, 0, XAUDIO2_DEFAULT_PROCESSOR ) ) )
    throw Platform::Exception::CreateException(hr);

IXAudio2MasteringVoice* pMasterVoice = nullptr;
if ( FAILED(hr = pXAudio2->CreateMasteringVoice( &pMasterVoice ) ) )
    return hr;
```

Is there anything I can do now?

Comment: Have you looked at the HRESULT of CreateSourceVoice?

Comment: I can't get it. The program breaks just like pSourceVoice and XAudio2 don't exist.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask - you need to show your code to allow others to reproduce the problem.

Comment: I found something new. CoInitializeEx( NULL, COINIT_MULTITHREADED ); This function failed at the first step.

Comment: What *version* of XAudio2 are you using?  XAudio 2.9, XAudio 2.8, legacy XAudio 2.7 from the DirectX SDK, or the [XAudio2Redist](https://aka.ms/XAudio2Redist) version of XAudio 2.9?

Comment: Based on the use of ``Platform::Exception`` I'm guessing you are writing a UWP app. In that case, ``CoIniitalizeEx`` is going to return ``S_FALSE`` or ``RPC_E_CHANGED_MODE`` because the Windows Runtime implicitly initializes COM.

Comment: I think I was using XAudio 2.7 from the DirectX9.0c SDK for a few years. This one worked well before the update.

Comment: No matter what version I use, the code should be the same, I guess. Is there something wrong with the windows10 update?

Comment: XAudio 2.7 from the DirectX SDK is *not supported* for UWP apps. In fact, you shouldn't use anything from the DirectX SDK when building UWP apps. Even for Win32 desktop apps, you shouldn't use XAudio 2.7 anymore. It's got a lot of known bugs. For Win32 desktop apps that are intended to run on versions of Windows older than Windows 10, use [XAudio2Redist](https://aka.ms/XAudio2Redist) instead which provides XAudio 2.9 for Windows 7 SP1 or later.

Comment: We still need to know what the ``HRESULT`` values are here that indicate failure. Also, it's important that you verify you are using the XAudio2 headers that match the XAUDIO2.LIB you are using. If you are mixing up DXSDK and Windows SDK stuff, it's going to have problems. You should try building some of the [XAudio2](https://github.com/walbourn/directx-sdk-samples/tree/master/XAudio2) samples to see if they build and run for you.

Comment: I installed XAudio2 2.9. It works now. Thank you very much for the help. Now I should try update the old apps with it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here seemed to be a mix of legacy DirectX SDK and newer Windows SDK headers in the build environment.

XAudio2 is fully supported on Windows 20H2 including it's various [version](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/xaudio2/xaudio2-versions).

Legacy XAudio 2.7 from the end-of-life DirectX SDK runs fine, as do all the legacy games and samples that use it. It is not part of the operating system and has to be installed via the legacy *DirectX End-User Runtime* package. See [Not So DirectSetup](https://walbourn.github.io/not-so-direct-setup/). DO NOT attempt to use the legacy DirectX SDK headers/libs to build UWP apps as they are not supported.

XAudio 2.8 and XAudio 2.9 are both built into the operating system, so these versions both work as well. These require using the headers from the Windows 8.x SDK and/or Windows 10 SDK. You must also set `_WINNT_WIN32` to `0x0602` (Windows 8), `0x0603` (Windows 8.1), or `0x0A00` (Windows 10) or these headers will error out. See [this blog post](https://walbourn.github.io/xaudio2-and-windows-8/).

If targeting Windows 10 only for Win32 desktop or UWP apps--or Xbox One/S/X and Xbox Series X/S development--use XAudio 2.9 which is built into the operating system.

If targeting Windows 7 SP1 or later, use the [XAudio2Redist](https://aka.ms/xaudio2redist) package which provides full XAudio 2.9 support with a simple side-by-side redist. This *does not* require the use of legacy DXSDK or DXSETUP.

If targeting Windows 8 or later, you can use XAudio 2.8 built in or [XAudio2Redist](https://aka.ms/xaudio2redist) if you want XAudio 2.9 for the xWMA support.

See also [Where is the DirectX SDK (2021 Edition)?](https://walbourn.github.io/where-is-the-directx-sdk-2021-edition/)

> If you are new to XAudio2, you should take a look at *DirectX Tool Kit for Audio* which is included in both the [DirectX 11](https://github.com/microsoft/DirectXTK/wiki/Getting-Started) and [DirectX 12](https://github.com/microsoft/DirectXTK12/wiki/Getting-Started) packages. It's an open source, lightweight audio library that uses XAudio2 and X3DAudio. It implements one-shot sounds, positional audio with optional reverb, voice-management, streaming audio, and wavebanks. It supports PCM, ADPCM, xWMA, and XMA2 (Xbox only) data. See [this blog post](https://walbourn.github.io/directx-tool-kit-for-audio/).